# Does setting `width` and `height` attributes in <picture> or its <img> do anything?

Tags: html, picture-element

I want to start using WebP on my site. I'm converting code that looks like this:

```
<img src="example.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Example">
```

To code that looks like this:

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="example.webp" type="image/webp">
  <img src="example.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Example">
</picture>
```

Where is the correct place to put the `width` and the `height` attributes? Does simply using the `height` and `width` attributes in the `<img>` element work, even when a `<source>` image is selected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, using the `height` and `width` attributes in the `<img>` element (and nowhere else) does work as intended. You don't need to try to set any attributes on the `<picture>` element.

Run this code snippet for proof:

```html
<p><code>&lt;img&gt;</code> without <code>height</code> and <code>width</code> attributes:</p>
<picture>
  <source srcset="https://a.webpurr.com/Ql62.webp" type="image/webp">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mraCN.jpg" alt="Example">
</picture>
<p><code>&lt;img&gt;</code> with <code>height</code> and <code>width</code> attributes:</p>
<picture>
  <source srcset="https://a.webpurr.com/Ql62.webp" type="image/webp">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mraCN.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Example">
</picture>
```

(If you see the images marked "JPEG", then you're using a browser that doesn't support WebP. If you don't see images, maybe the image host webpurr.com is down.)